# Node.js: forEach inside async.series

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I started developing my node.js app for work but i can't "think asynchronous".
In my function i have to do a query and for every rows i have to do another query to compute the final result and create my json.
I try to do this:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
            db.myCannedResponseList(req.params.websiteid, function(err,questions) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                ...
                callback();
            });
        },
    function(callback) {
            async.forEachSeries(temp,function(quest,callback) {
                    db.getCannedAnswer(quest.id, function(err,answers) {
                         console.log(answers);
                    });
            }, function(err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
            });
            callback();
        }
    ],
        function(err) { 
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json(output);
    });
```

But there is a problem: the result of *getCannedAnswer* is show after *res.json(output)*.
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to call the callback when the `forEachSeries` is done. You also need to call the callback that is passed to the `forEachSeries` handler functions:

```
async.forEachSeries(temp, function(quest, callback2) {
  db.getCannedAnswer(quest.id, function(err, answers) {
    console.log(answers);
    // call the callback for forEachSeries so it can proceed:
    callback2(); 
  });
}, callback); // forEachSeries is done here, call the callback for async.series
```

Comment: May be able to just pass `callback` in place of the anonymous `function(err)`. It'll `throw` on `return next(err);` since `next` doesn't exist there anyways (unless it's defined outside of the given snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Your async functions are nested and so need to be your callbacks.

Here's an approach:

```
    async.series([
        //async.apply(db.myCannedResponseList,req.params.websiteid), // This is equivalent to the first function below
        //db.myCannedResponseList(req.params.websiteid,callback), // This is equivalent too
        function(callback) {
            db.myCannedResponseList(req.params.websiteid, callback);
        },    
        function(callback) {
            // I'm not sure forEach is the best choice here
            // since it's callback isn't called with all the results so it won't be able to be forwarded...
            // Personally, I use async.times for something like this.
            async.times(temp.length,function(i,next) {
                db.getCannedAnswer(temp[i].id,next);
            },callback)
        }
     ],function(err) { 
          if (err) return next(err);
          res.json(output);
    });
```

I'm not sure what this function should do but if you encounter an error in `async.series` you should either call `res.json(500,error)` or not call `res` on success.

A good approach would be to separete this function altogether and have it call another callback when it's done. You would then call `res` there.

Also, instead of passing an array to `async.series` you can pass an object so the results will be namespaced.

Full example:

```
    function getCannedStuff(data,callback){
        async.series({
            list : async.apply(db.myCannedResponseList,data.websiteid),
            answer : function(cb) {
                async.times(data.temp.length,function(i,next) {
                db.getCannedAnswer(data.temp[i].id,next);
                },cb)
            }
        },callback);  
    }
```

Then call the function from another module:

```
    getCannedStuff({
        websiteid: req.params.websiteid,
        temp:temp
    },function(error,results) {
        console.log(results.list);
        console.log(results.answer);
        if(err) return res.json(500,{error : error});
        res.json(results)
    });
```

You should decide if you want to control the error inside or outside `getCannedStuff` but it's a good approach to pass them along and not do all the time `if(err)` to see if they occur.

Comment: calling `next(err)` in case of errors in the final callback is pretty standard behaviour for Express apps that have an app-wide error handler defined.

Comment: @robertklep True. Just trying to make my point with the example